# Can ARC manage non-toll-free-bridged Core Foundation objects?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

If I have a **non-toll-free-bridged** Core Foundation object, can I safely transfer ownership to ARC, or is that privilege reserved for toll-free-bridged types?

For example:

```
- (id)myBundle {
    CFBundleRef b = CFBundleCreate(NULL, self.bundleURL);
    return b == NULL ? nil : (__bridge_transfer id)b;
}

- (UInt32)myBundleVersionNumber {
    return CFBundleGetVersionNumber((__bridge CFBundleRef)self.myBundle);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every CoreFoundation object (`CFTypeRef`) is also an Objective-C object (`id`).

In the old days, before `CFAutorelease()` was introduced in 10.9, non-ARC code would autorelease CoreFoundation objects using the `[(id)<CFTypeRef> autorelease]` idiom which was possible due to CoreFoundation objects being Objective-C objects.

The correspondence is why in ARC a CoreFoundation object can be `__bridge_transfer`'ed to ARC.

So the answer is yes, you can safely transfer ownership of any CoreFoundation object to ARC.

If you step through your sample code at the assembler level you will find ARC calling `_objc_release` which in turn will end up calling `CFRelease`.

*Note:* The toll-free bridged objects are those where there are exact equivalents in CoreFoundation and Objective-C so they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Put another way, `CFType`, the "base class" of Core Foundation is toll-free bridged to `NSObject`.

Comment: @KenThomases - Yes, but unfortunately its not listed in [Apple's table](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010677-SW4) of toll-free bridged types so I went for a more wordy explanation.

Comment: Sure. It wasn't a criticism, just an addition.

Comment: @KenThomases - It wasn't taken as one, no problem. Just that it would be nice if Apple did put it in their table, then the answer could have been shorter!

Comment: Note that not all Cocoa objects are sub-classes of NSObject (NSProxy and OSObject's for example) and some CF Objects are not necessarily toll-free bridged to their Cocoa counter parts (like CFBundle <-> NSBundle). And KenT's comment is wrong: CFType is NOT toll-free bridged to NSObject.